# PHP: Extracting a value from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

In this array, I am attempting to extract the value int(2128) from the ["member_count"] key.

```
array(3) {
["total"]=>
int(1)
["data"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
      array(17) {
        ["id"]=>
      string(10) "999999999999"
        ["web_id"]=>
      int(421097)
        ["name"]=>
      string(21) "Name Of List"
        ["date_created"]=>
      string(19) "2014-07-14 13:51:01"
        ["email_type_option"]=>
      bool(false)
        ["use_awesomebar"]=>
      bool(true)
        ["default_from_name"]=>
      string(14) "Department Name"
        ["default_from_email"]=>
      string(24) "user@email.com"
        ["default_subject"]=>
      string(0) ""
        ["default_language"]=>
      string(2) "en"
        ["list_rating"]=>
      float(3.5)
        ["subscribe_url_short"]=>
      string(23) "website/4545"
        ["subscribe_url_long"]=>
      string(91) "website"
        ["beamer_address"]=>
      string(47) "key goes here"
        ["visibility"]=>
      string(3) "pub"
        ["stats"]=>
          array(16) {
            ["member_count"]=>
              int(2128)
            ["unsubscribe_count"]=>
              int(20)
            ["cleaned_count"]=>
              int(57)
            ["member_count_since_send"]=>
              int(1)
            ["unsubscribe_count_since_send"]=>
              int(9)
            ["cleaned_count_since_send"]=>
              int(29)
            ["campaign_count"]=>
              int(2)
            ["grouping_count"]=>
              int(1)
            ["group_count"]=>
              int(4)
            ["merge_var_count"]=>
              int(6)
            ["avg_sub_rate"]=>
              int(17)
            ["avg_unsub_rate"]=>
              int(3)
            ["target_sub_rate"]=>
              int(17)
            ["open_rate"]=>
              float(38.672399892502)
            ["click_rate"]=>
              float(14.932747735383)
            ["date_last_campaign"]=>
              string(19) "2014-11-07 19:14:30"
    }
    ["modules"]=>
       array(0) {
    }
  }
}
  ["errors"]=>
     array(0) {
  }
}
```

Here is the PHP that I have so far but I'm unable to get just the value "int(2128)"

```
  foreach($result as $row){
    foreach($row[0] as $row1){

   echo '<pre>';
   var_dump($row1['member_count']);
   echo '</pre>';
     }
  }
```

The Results I get:

```
string(1) "6"

NULL

string(1) "F"

string(1) "2"

NULL

NULL

string(1) "B"

string(1) "d"

string(0) ""

string(1) "e"

NULL

string(1) "h"

string(1) "h"

string(1) "u"

string(1) "p"

int(2128)

NULL
```

I greatly appreciate any help to narrow the results down to just the value "int(2128)".

Thanks.

Comment: looks like something went wrong when you pasted the array. The indentation is off, which makes it pretty hard to visually debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the value `2128` use this:

```
$array['data'][0]['stats']['member_count']
```

($array is the name of your multidimensional array)